# Storing two variables into one

Tags: php, variables

How shall I store two variable into one?

Here is an example,

```
$a = 'hello';

$b = 'hola';

A way is array like,

$c = array('a', 'b');

$myvariables = $c;

echo $myvariables[0];
```

but how can I preserve the values of $a & $b into $c without using array something like

```
$c = ($a + $b)?
```

Comment: Perhaps use an Object?

Comment: I seriously don't get the downvotes to this. It's a beginner question, but it's a question that does show some efforts into finding the solution and is perfectly valid within the limits of StackOverflow. The PHP community really does seem polluted.

Comment: And the same goes for the close votes; "unclear what you're asking". Unclear? It's perfectly clear. Don't try to mine for 'raising helpful flags' badges please ...

Comment: @Sherlock To me it's an unclear question. I think I should be allowed to indicate that without being accused of 'flag mining'. If you know so well, then rather than flaming, you could add a comment that might help us understand the question better.

Comment: @Sherlock the reason for downvote is the laziness of OP. when you search in google with question title itself you get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6565237/1771402) as top result which answers him

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean concatenation?

```
$c = $a.$b;
```

Comment: @Daan, It's something like act the same with `$c` as `$a+$b` or `3+2=5`. if the other meaning of concentration is addition this is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

When storing variables, there is a difference when you use single quotes and double quotes. If you use single quotes, the variable names stay intact. If you use double quotes, however, PHP will interpret them as variables. Here is an example:

```
$a = "hello";
$b = "world";
$c = '$a $b';
echo $c;
$d = "$a $b";
echo "</br>";
echo $d;
```

This will output:

```
$a $b
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the values in a string and split them later, you may define a delimitter (Like | or ; ) and String your values together.

```
$a = "hello";
$b = "world";
$delimitter = "|";
$array = array($a,$b);
// add new values
array_push($array, "Get", $b);

$stringlist = implode($delimitter, $array);
// $stringlist = "hello|world|Get|world";

// and to get them back
$array = explode($stringlist,$delimitter);
// you may even directly access a value:
$a= explode($stringlist,$delimitter)[0];
```